# What happened to to the startup application preferences?

Tags: startup-applications

in 11.04 I can go to system->preferences ->startup applications
and do things like uncheck Gnome Login Sound
when I open Startup Applications in 11.10 the screen is empty

Comment: Just curious... do you have at least ubuntu one or the updater there?

Comment: I have an ubuntu one account and I have run update manager

Answer (score 7):

The behavior I've discovered is the same as KDEs (local .desktops override system ones) so to be able to deselect/select items in 'Startup Applications' do this:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart # If not already created
cd ~/.config/autostart
cp /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop .
sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" *.desktop
```

Then pick your Startup Applications from the Startup Applications control panel.  From there, "Log Out/Login" to apply (thanks to duffydack).

Answer (score 3):

This may help you: http://maketecheasier.com/disable-login-sound-in-ubuntu-oneiric-quick-tips/2011/09/15

Apparently, .desktop files now have an option to not appear in the startup application preferences in 11.10. Setting this option to FALSE, makes this items appear in the startup preferences and then you can disable it.

EDIT: As Jo-Erlend Schinstad said, the link may not be available. So, I'll explain the idea here.

The solution is to change the .desktop file of the application you want to see in the startup preferences. For example, for the login sound, you have to open the file:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/gnome/autostart/libcanberra-login-sound.desktop
```

Then change the line that says

```
NoDisplay=true
```

to

```
NoDisplay=false
```

Comment: That is an external link, and that means it might go away without warning, making your answer useless. For that reason, it would be better to explain it in your answer.

Comment: Thank you, the link provides a good solution for gnome sound and screen saver

Answer (score 1):

To enable them all again, run

```
find /etc/xdg/autostart/ -name "*.desktop" -exec sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" '{}' \;
```

This will work but would only be temporary.  For example:

```
dpkg -S /etc/xdg/autostart/ubuntuone-launch.desktop 
ubuntuone-client: /etc/xdg/autostart/ubuntuone-launch.desktop
```

So if ubuntuone-client gets updated it will disappear from 'Startup Applications'.  A developer told me when I had a similar situation with KDE to first copy the .desktop file to ~/.kde4/share/kde4/services/ and edit it there (the local one will override the system one); be nice if Gnome had this too here.

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution that replaces all the autostart options!

Comment: thanks for the extra info regarding local overriding system, never knew that.

Comment: @AwmLamp Welcome to askubuntu, and remember to upvote good answers.