# Empty Startup Application

Tags: 12.04, startup-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to to the startup application preferences?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66910/what-happened-to-to-the-startup-application-preferences)

Since I upgraded my system to 12.04 and did some updates, Startup Applications (gnome-session-property) is empty. Is that correct? (I don't think so...).

Note: I tried to run it as sudo but it doesn't work either.

Tks...

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you provide detail on your question? Gnome version, and screenshot will be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that you upgraded from 10.04 to 12.04.

At Ubuntu 12.04 yes , the startup applications are hidden. Is not a problem or a fail that the catalog is empty. Its more like a security "valve" so users not delete any essential startup application and corrupt the system.

Here is a way to reveal all the startup applications in Ubuntu 12.04.

**Be careful , because the following command will reveal ALL the startup applications.**

Open a terminal and give this command

`sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop`

Then open again the startup applications and I'm certain that the list will have grown.

Comment: I just saw the answer to my question in another website ten minutes before I see yours. About the previous version used, no it wasn't. It's a brand new installation, I misspelled the original question saying "upgraded". By the way, there's other users with the same problem and still with no answers. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for above post. I was facing the same problem and with above command I resolved my problem.